# when i click logout i want my session to get over or null

Tags: node.js, session

i have logout link in my app which redirects to login page. but i also want that after clicking logout my req.session also get destroyed. how to perfom this task.
this is front end

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <p
                    class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                    href="#"
                    id="navbarDropdown"
                    role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                   <%= userName %>
                  <p>
                   
                    <% if( userStatus == true){%>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Account</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="logout" href="/login">logout</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    <%}%>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

how to do this in font end or back end

i am using following to create the session and i want to destroy it when clicking logout

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import session from "express-session";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
require("babel-core/register");
require("babel-polyfill");

const AuthRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const ProductRoutes = require("./routes/product");
const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret key",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
//var MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

const dbURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Sports-Arena";
mongoose.connect(dbURL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", function () {
  console.log("connected", dbURL);
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

require("./routes")(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using express-session its should be work

```
req.session.destroy();
```

Otherwise I need more information, how you start your session backend?

Comment: @DevDeveloper i am storing user as req.session.user when i login or register in my app. will req.session. destroy() work in front end as i cant post to any route when i click logout on front end

Comment: Can you please edit your question above and show us some code from your session creation section? That will be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. So you can add simple in your routing for /logout where your handle also the render part req.session.destroy(); its should be work